Change title of theorem in beamer
I use beamer class with style Madrid.
Sometimes I want to use my own titles in a theorem-box, e.g. Assumption instead of Theorem.
Everything else shall remain unchanged.
How can I achieve that?
I have this:

and the second box should be labelled assumption.
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{german}[babel]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlaute
\usepackage[german, linesnumbered, boxruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
    I know the following: 
    
    \begin{theorem}
        There are infinitely friendly people on Stackexchange.
    \end{theorem}

But I do not know:
    \begin{theorem}
        There are infinitely friendly people on 9gag.
    \end{theorem}

    \end{document}


Behind the scenes, beamer uses the amsthm package to create theorems. This means you can use \newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption} to create a new theorem-like environment yourself:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlaute
\usepackage[german, linesnumbered, boxruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    I know the following: 
    
    \begin{theorem}
        There are infinitely friendly people on \url{https://topanswers.xyz/tex}.
    \end{theorem}

But I do not know:
    \begin{assumption}
        There are infinitely friendly people on \url{https://powerusers.codidact.com}.
    \end{assumption}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Some other notes about the code:

No need to load the xcolor package, beamer loads it automatically.

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} has been the default for several years now. Should no longer be necessary if your tex distribution is reasonable up-to-date

Did you mean \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}?



That was easy, thank you!!

@Lereu You're welcome!
